# Android ImageView draw image from right and scale to height of view

Tags: android, imageview

So I have an ImageView with a set height and width, but would like the image to be scaled to the height of the view, and then drawn "from the right" or should I say end of the view, so that the left part of the image that doesn't fit just isn't displayed. 
How could I accomplish this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using `iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_END);`

Comment: This makes the image scale by width, so it reduces its height and puts it in the bottom right corner.. I need it to scale by height, and chop off the extra width.

Answer (score 0):

try `imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.centerInside)`

Comment: that doesn't cut it either.. I mean I tried all of the options none of them fit my description, I'm looking for perhabs a subclass of ImageView that would do that.